# how to Highlight being read words in text to speech asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm am building a web app and need a text to speech which highlights the text being read at the moment. I built the text to speech but don't have any idea how to tackle the highlighting of text are there any tips or functions for this problem?
10x a lot.

Comment: this can be done only with javascript. Also no one can help you with out the actually code of the part that you need to solve, and sound complicate.

Comment: Need some code, and as Aristos said this is only feasible with Javascript unless you are using Flash/Silverlight(which I would doubt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Web app, so the highlighting must be done on the client.

I guess the TTS transform is done on the server. Could you also generate a timeline along with the sound ("from millisecond *m1* to *m2*, the phrase between positions *p1* and *p2* is spoken")? Then client-side javascript has a handle on when to highlight what portion of the text.

Next challenge: have playback and higlighting start/stop at the same time.

Comment: yes i think i will be using the rangy.js for this as it would give me word by word as ranges and put it in a span so that i can add the background style, the only thing missing is the offset were the text to speech is at the moment and i think that this is possible too using speakstream but about this i dont know exactly